# Is Jmeter can run on the servers and give the load testing for a particular web application

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can Jmeter will able be available to run on the servers and generate report and check load testing of a web application

Comment: Yes that's possible.

Comment: Not satisfied with the answer? Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how that is done, can you guide me how the load testing is perform in Jmeter some kind of understandable link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend installing JMeter on the same machines where your application lives as JMeter uses a lot of system resources during load test and it's better to use separate machines to avoid mutual interference.

In order to get started:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)